# Looking at Automorphisms of Subgroups of $(\mathbb R,+)$ With Positive Slope

Tags: real-numbers, automorphism-group, ordered-groups

Let $(R,+)$ be a non-trivial subgroup of $(\mathbb R,+)$.

We say that an automorphism $\phi$ of $R$ has positive slope if

$\tag 1 \phi(R \cap \mathbb R^{\gt 0}) \subset \mathbb R^{\gt 0}$

> What conditions must be put on $R$ to guarantee that
>
> For every $x,  y \in R \cap \mathbb R^{\gt 0}$ there is one and only one automorphism of positive slope $\phi$
> such that $\phi(x) = y$.

**My Work**

I know that when $R = \mathbb R$ the automorphism can always be found. I suspect that it is true provided $R$ can be n̶a̶t̶u̶r̶a̶l̶l̶y̶ endowed with a multiplicative structure using the automorphisms. You can call any positive element in $R$ the unit of measure $1$ and you get a field (the automorphisms form a group).

Of interest here is the wikipedia article on [Cauchy's functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation).

Comment: An automorphism of positive slope is injective, so you must have $x=y$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Expanding on @Mindlack's comment, probably you mean $\phi(x)=y$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes (fixed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that we can safely assume $x<y$; otherwise, just look at the inverse map.*

First, note that $R$ must be dense in order to have *any* nontrivial automorphisms of positive slope. (Put another way, the group $\mathbb{Z}$ has exactly two automorphisms, only the identity has positive slope, and any discrete subgroup of $R$ is isomorphic - indeed, *ambiently* isomorphic - to $\mathbb{Z}$.)

*From now on, $R$ is a **dense** subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.*

Second, note that any automorphism of positive slope must be order-preserving on positive elements: if $x>y>0$ but $f(x)<f(y)$, then we would have $x-y>0$ but $f(x-y)<0$.

This means that any automorphism $f$ of $R$ with positive slope extends uniquely to an automorphism $\hat{f}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive slope. Namely, given $r\in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ we pick an increasing sequence $a_1<a_2<...$ of elements of $R$ with $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}a_i=r$. Then $f(a_1)<f(a_2)<...$, and this sequence is bounded above (since $R_{>r}\not=\emptyset$), so it has some limit $s$. It's now easy to check that two different sequences of $a$s yield the same $s$ and that the map $r\mapsto s$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ with positive slope.

But the automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ of positive slope are exactly the maps of the form $x\mapsto cx$ for $c\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, and in particular are determined by where they move any single nonzero value; so if an automorphism of $R$ with positive slope moving $x$ to $y$ exists, it must be unique.

---

So now we're left only with the *existence* task. But in light of the classification above, this is easy: $R$ has the desired property iff for every $0<x<y$ in $R$ the map $z\mapsto {yz\over x}$ is defined on $R$ - that is, iff for any $x,y,z$ in $R$ with $0<x<y$ we have ${yz\over x}\in R$.

Trivially any subfield of $\mathbb{R}$ has this property; conversely, if $1\in R$ and $R$ has this property then $R$ is a field. Any such $R$ can be "multiplicatively scaled" to an $\hat{R}$ containing $1$; when we do this, we preserve the above property and so get a field. Conversely, by the same reasoning any multiplicative scaling of a field has this property (e.g. $R=\{q\pi:q\in\mathbb{Q}\}$).

So this gives a complete answer to your question:

> $R$ has the property in question iff $R=\{cx: x\in F\}$ for some field $F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and some nonzero constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I used a countdown. When I saw I had something in my inbox within the allotted time, I knew that you would have the answer. As you can see I was fixing up my question to try to get out the same thing. A bit disheartening to see you quickly THINK-N-TYPE a response, as I stumble along , I have to wonder now if you are an AI BOT! But all tongue-in-cheek aside, thanks for your assistance.